# How can I use the protected route in admin panel?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react theme for admin panel. I added a login page and I want to make a protected route. Index.js has two routes, but there are more routes in the admin panel. I haven't done a protected route to the admin panel before, so I'm really struggling. Right now, I can only check the redirects from the login page. I want no access to other routes without tokens.

**index.js:**

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
// import indexRoutes from "./routes/index.jsx";
import { BrowserRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./layouts/Login/Login";
import FullLayout from "./layouts/fulllayout.jsx";
import "./assets/scss/style.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      {localStorage.token?.length > 500 ? <Route path="/" component={FullLayout} /> :  <Redirect from="/dashboard" to="/login"/>}
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**FullLayout.js:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "../components/header/header.jsx";
import Sidebar from "../components/sidebar/sidebar.jsx";
import Footer from "../components/footer/footer.jsx";
import ThemeRoutes from "../routes/routing.jsx";

const FullLayout = (props) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updateDimensions = () => {
      let element = document.getElementById("main-wrapper");
      setWidth(window.innerWidth);
      if (width < 1170) {
        element.setAttribute("data-sidebartype", "mini-sidebar");
        element.classList.add("mini-sidebar");
      } else {
        element.setAttribute("data-sidebartype", "full");
        element.classList.remove("mini-sidebar");
      }
    };
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
      updateDimensions();
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateDimensions.bind(this));
    window.addEventListener("load", updateDimensions.bind(this));
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("load", updateDimensions.bind(this));
      window.removeEventListener("resize", updateDimensions.bind(this));
    };
  }, [width]);

  return (
    <div
      id="main-wrapper"
      data-theme="light"
      data-layout="vertical"
      data-sidebartype="full"
      data-sidebar-position="fixed"
      data-header-position="fixed"
      data-boxed-layout="full"
    >
      <Header />
      <Sidebar {...props} routes={ThemeRoutes} />
      <div className="page-wrapper d-block">
        <div className="page-content container-fluid">
          <Switch>
            {ThemeRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
              if (prop.redirect) {
                return <Redirect from={prop.path} to={prop.pathTo} key={key} />;
              } else {
                return (
                  <Route
                    exact
                    path={prop.path}
                    component={prop.component}
                    key={key}
                  />
                );
              }
            })}
          </Switch>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default FullLayout;
```

**routing.js:**

```
// ui components
import Alerts from '../views/ui-components/alert.jsx';
import Badges from '../views/ui-components/badge.jsx';
import Buttons from '../views/ui-components/button.jsx';
import Cards from '../views/ui-components/cards.jsx';
import LayoutComponent from '../views/ui-components/layout.jsx';
import PaginationComponent from '../views/ui-components/pagination.jsx';
import PopoverComponent from '../views/ui-components/popover.jsx';
import TooltipComponent from '../views/ui-components/tooltip.jsx';

const ThemeRoutes = [
  { 
    path: '/dashboard', 
    name: 'Dashboard', 
    icon: 'mdi mdi-gauge', 
    component: Starter 
  },
  {
    path: '/alert',
    name: 'Alerts',
    icon: 'mdi mdi-comment-processing-outline',
    component: Alerts
  },
  {
    path: '/badge',
    name: 'Badges',
    icon: 'mdi mdi-arrange-send-backward',
    component: Badges
  },
  {
    path: '/button',
    name: 'Buttons',
    icon: 'mdi mdi-toggle-switch',
    component: Buttons
  },
  {
    path: '/card',
    name: 'Cards',
    icon: 'mdi mdi-credit-card-multiple',
    component: Cards
  },
  {
    path: '/grid',
    name: 'Grid',
    icon: 'mdi mdi-apps',
    component: LayoutComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/pagination',
    name: 'Pagination',
    icon: 'mdi mdi-priority-high',
    component: PaginationComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/popover',
    name: 'Popover',
    icon: 'mdi mdi-pencil-circle',
    component: PopoverComponent
  },
  {
    path: '/ui-components/tooltip',
    name: 'Toltips',
    icon: 'mdi mdi-image-filter-vintage',
    component: TooltipComponent
  },
  { path: '/', pathTo: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', redirect: true }
];
export default ThemeRoutes;
```

Answer (score 0):

in Your full layout try this one

```
{ThemeRoutes.map((route, key) => {
            return route.component? (
              <Route
                key={key}
                path={route.path}
                name={route.name}
                render={props => (
                      localStorage.getItem("token") ? (
                        <CFade><route.component {...props} /></CFade>
                      ):(
                        <Redirect to={{pathname: "/login"}} />
                      )
                )} />
            ):null
          })}
```

Comment: where in the full layout should the above code go to? I have a similar problem with Berry React Admin template

Comment: put it where your rendering your content components